# Parent Module Components Error When Navigating To SubModule Lazy Loaded Route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a base AppModule which handles the routes for that Module, then I have a sub module with it's own `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` that I'm using to build a wizard. All routes in the AppModule works as designed, but when I attempt to "lazyload" my wizard module, I get the error "Error: Component LoginComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module."

This Component is part of my AppModule Routing as I use this route to login to the app. All routing works fine until I Click on the "activate-mail-base" route, then it throws the error referencing the LoginComponent. I believe I am coding this to the documentation specs, but obviously missing something.

SubModule Routing

```
//wizard.routing.module
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
//Component Imports
import { ActivateMailBaseComponent } from './activate-mail-base/activate-mail-base.component';
import { ActivateMailStep1Component } from './activate-mail-step1/activate-mail-step1.component';
import { ActivateMailStep2Component } from './activate-mail-step2/activate-mail-step2.component';
import { ActivateMailStep3Component } from './activate-mail-step3/activate-mail-step3.component';
import { ActivateMailStep4Component } from './activate-mail-step4/activate-mail-step4.component';
import { ActivateMailStep5Component } from './activate-mail-step5/activate-mail-step5.component';

export const activateMailRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'activate-mail-1' },
  { path: 'activate-mail-1', component: ActivateMailStep1Component},
  { path: 'activate-mail-2', component: ActivateMailStep2Component},
  { path: 'activate-mail-3', component: ActivateMailStep3Component},
  { path: 'activate-mail-4', component: ActivateMailStep4Component},
  { path: 'activate-mail-5', component: ActivateMailStep5Component}
];
```

SubModule

```
//activate-mailorder-module.module
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { LeftRailModule } from '../../leftRailComponent/left-rail.module'; //This contains router links
import { activateMailRoutes } from './wizard.routing.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
CommonModule,
RouterModule.forChild(activateMailRoutes),
LeftRailModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class ActivateMailorderModuleModule {}
```

This is AppModuleRouting

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './loginComponent/login.component';
import { CreateFormComponent } from './Campaigns/createForm/createForm.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './Interceptors/not-found/not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'activate-mail-base', loadChildren: './MYPATH/activateMemberMailorder/activate-mailorder-module.module#ActivateMailorderModuleModule'},
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/login' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'create-form', component: CreateFormComponent },
  { path: 'not-found', component: NotFoundComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{ enableTracing: true })
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [RouterModule, CommonModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

export const routingComponents = [LoginComponent, CreateFormComponent, NotFoundComponent];
```

Import into AppModule - ABRV For Space

```
//Routing
import { AppRoutingModule, routingComponents } from './routing.module';
@ngModule({
  declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      routingComponents
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      FormsModule,
      HttpModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      MomentModule,
      LeftRailModule,
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you defined `routingComponents` like this:

```
export const routingComponents = [LoginComponent, CreateFormComponent, NotFoundComponent];
```

And in your `AppModule` you're using it in the `declarations` array, you'll have to spread it like this(`...routingComponents`).

Give this a try:

```
import { AppRoutingModule, routingComponents } from './routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...routingComponents
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, still throwing the same ERROR. It makes me wonder if I broke all my components (asied form AppComponent) out into a featureModule and then include that in my Wizard and App modules, if that would send the LoginComponent to both. The odd thing is, notihing in the Wizard Module even uses the LoginComponent.

Comment: That's really strange. You've added `LoginComponent` to the `declarations` array of your `AppModule`. So ideally, it should be recognized by the Angular. But it's still giving this error which kind of doesn't make any sense. Would it be possible for you to create a StackBlitz replicating this issue?